# Select by -3 days?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to select data from a specific table in my database, but I want to be able to only view the last 3 days worth of data, I have the following code but for some reason I can't get it to work.

```
SELECT * FROM demands WHERE t.date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may avoid usage of `DATE_ADD()` at all:

```
SELECT * FROM demands as t WHERE t.date >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

As **@OGHaza** mentioned, you specified column with alias to nowhere: `t.date` should be just `date` (note that it is a reserved word, so *you should use backticks around it in this case*) or `demands` should be specified with an alias like `demands as t`.